# Where to find used resources for Elastic beanstalk app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an app deployed on Elastic beanstalk. The app is a war file which runs some processing of text content received from a separate service. What pricing considerations should I make ?

The processing of the content can be intensive and may take a couple of hours to run. I'm eligible for the "AWS Free Usage Tier" but im not sure where I can view my current usage.

I'd like to see a % breakdown of CPU clock cycles, memory etc.

For example google app engine offers a handy breakdown of % used resources :

[image]

is there something similar for AWS ? in this case specifically an app running on Elastic beanstalk ?

Update : Answers to this question are some help : [What is the AWS Elastic Beanstalk CPU cap on the Free Tier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297647/what-is-the-aws-elastic-beanstalk-cpu-cap-on-the-free-tier?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few levels of Elastic Beanstalk monitoring.

**Elastic Beanstalk console**
It is very simple, just to give you a rough idea what is happening in your system.

[image]

**Basic CloudWatch metrics**
Available under EC2 > Instances > Monitoring

[image]

**CloudWatch metrics**
Each service has a set of metrics to give you the best view into what's happening with your system.

Here's just the number of metrics I have available for the services used by my instances:

```
DynamoDB Metrics: 65
    Table Metrics: 26
    Table Operation Metrics: 38
    Account Metrics: 1

SNS Metrics: 8
    Topic Metrics: 8

EBS Metrics: 16
    Per-Volume Metrics: 16

EC2 Metrics: 40
    Per-Instance Metrics: 20
    By Auto Scaling Group: 20

ElastiCache Metrics: 91
    ElastiCache: 19
    CacheClusterId: 36
    Cache Node Metrics: 36
```

You can measure practically anything meaningful. And you can even add your own metrics to CloudWatch.

In addition, you can set CloudWatch alarms to send you a notification if something goes above the threshold.

Read [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) guide to get a better idea.

About breakdown, I did not see any graphs for breakdown for Free Tier. If there's a Free Tier offer for the service, and you are trying to use more, then your requests will either be throttled (with DynamoDB) or you will start paying for the service above Free Tier (with SNS).

Look in your account Billing and Cost Management to see if you are going way above Free Tier. Click on Bills, then breakdown by service. Again, you can set-up a monitoring to be notified if your expenses are going to be above pre-set threshold.

Honestly, I find AWS more straightforward and flexible in terms of monitoring and payments than GAE. You definitely get more for the same money.

Comment: thanks, I'd just like to add that an alarm can be set by clicking the alarm icon for each monitoring section